# I am trying to refresh the data in form2 if the value from form1 is changed when the form2 is already loaded

Tags: c#

I have two forms `Form1` and `Form2`and I showed details from `Form1` in `Form2`. I am trying to refresh the data in `Form2` if the value from `Form1` is changed when the `Form2` is already loaded. I have displayed the details in `Form2` `Form_Load()` event.

Can any one help me to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can build up a Custom Event of Form1 and Probably you Know when Form1 is Changed ,if it's Changed than refresh Data @Form2 assuming that Control's in Form2 are Public(those who contain Data's from Form1) . Or you can put a Background-worker which check's if changes made at Form1 and proceed with Population.

Answer (score 0):

Move logic from onload event to public function and call it from onload event and from form1 too.

Comment: I am pretty sure this would cause an exception, unless he was sure to do a Control.Invoke, I assume this second form is being displayed in a thread-safe way otherwise Form1 couldn't be modified if Form2 was up.

Answer (score 0):

1. Handle the "Changed" events of the controls in Form1.
2. Create custom events in Form1 (for data change) and fire these custom events from the control's "Changed" event handler.
3. Handle these custom events of Form1 in Form2 and update the Form2 controls accordingly.